# local variable in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, local-variables

I writed recursive function named pascal_n to implement Pascal's triangle.
return type of pascal_n is int * and I declared local variable int * pre_ptr,int *cur_ptr.
cur_ptr points 1d array cur_arr[MAX].
But Even in recursive functions, I understanded that local variable disappears when the function ends, but why can I assign a return value (address value) to pre_ptr and access pre_ptr[]? Even if pascla_n returns cur_ptr,cur_ptr points cur_arr,local variable. How does this code work?

This part

**pre_ptr=pascal_n(n-1);**

**cur_ptr[i+1]=pre_ptr[i]+pre_ptr[i+1];**

full code ↓

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 51

int* pascal_n(int n) {
    int prev_arr[MAX];  
    int cur_arr[MAX];
    int *cur_ptr=cur_arr;
    int *pre_ptr;
    int k=0;
    cur_arr[k]=1;
    k++;
    if(n==1){
        cur_arr[0]=1;
        printf("1\n");
        return cur_ptr;
    }
    else {
        pre_ptr=pascal_n(n-1);
        for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++){
            cur_ptr[i+1]=pre_ptr[i]+pre_ptr[i+1];
            k++;
        }
    }
    cur_arr[k]=1;
    for(int j=0;j<=k;j++)
        printf("%d ",cur_arr[j]); 
    printf("\n");
    return cur_ptr;
}

int main() {
  int n;

  scanf("%d", &n);
  pascal_n(n);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `pascal_n` function returns a pointer to the first element in the local `cur_arr` array. As any other local variables, the life-time of the array will end together with the current function invocation, i.e. when the current call to the function returns. The pointer will immediately become invalid, and any attempt to dereference it will lead to *undefined behavior*. Pass the array to use as an *argument* to the function instead.

Comment: Undefined behavior sometimes presents itself as behaving the way you expect.  In this case, the local array for the n==1 case is (probably: speculating about undefined behavior is ill-advised!) "low" on the call stack and its values are not being over written.  Although it is against the language model to use that memory, it is "working" as you expect.

Comment: *Every time* you call a function it makes a new set of local variables and those are destroyed when *that call* returns.

Answer (score 0):

You return cur_ptr, which you previously set to point to the first element of the `cur_arr` array. `cur_arr` however, is defined within the function, and so it exists entirely on the stack, and so when the function ends, the program can no longer be sure that the data will be maintained: later calling another function may overwrite the data pointed to by `cur_ptr`. What you have to do instead, is either create new arrays dynamically, with either `malloc` or `new`, or declare a lot of global arrays (array of arrays) and point to them instead.

For example, if you had some other function that you needed to call, that also needed a lot of stack memory, it would corrupt your data:

```
int* pascal_n(int n) {
    int prev_arr[MAX];  
    int cur_arr[MAX];
    int *cur_ptr=cur_arr;
    int *pre_ptr;
    int k=0;
    cur_arr[k]=1;
    k++;
    if(n==1){
        cur_arr[0]=1;
        printf("1\n");
        return cur_ptr;
    }
    else {
        pre_ptr=pascal_n(n-1);
        for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++){
            cur_ptr[i+1]=pre_ptr[i]+pre_ptr[i+1];
            k++;
        }
    }
    cur_arr[k]=1;
    for(int j=0;j<=k;j++)
        printf("%d ",cur_arr[j]); 
    printf("\n");
    return cur_ptr;
}

void someOtherFunction() {
   int arr[5000];
   for(int i=0;i<5000;i++)
      arr[i] = 8474382;
}

int main() {
  int n;

  scanf("%d", &n);
  int* data=pascal_n(n);
  someOtherFunction();
  printf("%d\n",*data);
  return 0;
}
```

The above program, would first print the correct values, but if you then tried to use the value returned by the function to read the data again, it will have been changed by the other function.

Comment: But the program to run, operate normally. if I input 3, it prints three-layer Pascal triangle

Comment: Yes, but if you call another function, then your data will become corrupted:

Comment: Try the new program